# Why this operation results in a tensor full of 'nan'?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

`err = reduce((mu_students - teacher_pred)**2, 'b h w vec -> b h w', 'sum')`

where **mu_students** and **teacher_pred** are 2 tensors with size (1,14,14,256).
The two tensors do not contain nan values before the reduce.

Moreover, this exact same operation work fine with the previous layer of the network, when **mu_students** and **teacher_pred** have size = (1,28,28,128). This error presents itself only on one kind of images (but it shouldn't be related to size, because images are always resized to 224)

Comment: update: even 'err = reduce((teacher_pred), 'b h w vec -> b h w', 'sum')' returns the same tensor full of 'nan'. There is something wrong in the reduce

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more about the function **reduce** and the input tensors?
By assuming that;

- (1) **reduce** is from **einops** and written as
  `from einops import reduce as reduce`
- (2) **mu_students** and **teacher_pred** is random tensors,

when I try this code on Google Colab, it works well without NaN.

```
!pip install einops
from einops import reduce as reduce
mu_students = torch.rand(1,14,14,256)
teacher_pred = torch.rand(1,14,14,256)
err = reduce((mu_students - teacher_pred)**2, 'b h w vec -> b h w', 'sum')
```

The values are, for example,

```
# mu_students
tensor([[[[0.4079, 0.5835, 0.6807,  ..., 0.6041, 0.7366, 0.9291],
          [0.0338, 0.9161, 0.7018,  ..., 0.6035, 0.1816, 0.4059],
          [0.5949, 0.9535, 0.1460,  ..., 0.4049, 0.5120, 0.0734], ...

# teacher_pred
tensor([[[[0.7493, 0.2193, 0.6465,  ..., 0.6262, 0.0270, 0.5532],
          [0.5343, 0.9384, 0.9916,  ..., 0.2127, 0.0370, 0.6322],
          [0.3568, 0.7474, 0.5562,  ..., 0.0589, 0.1356, 0.6062], ...
# err
tensor([[[42.6367, 36.5668, 42.7598, 37.0643, 40.7744, 43.6076, 45.5338,
          45.3421, 40.0736, 45.2035, 43.3516, 40.8768, 39.1142, 40.8736],
         [50.8344, 40.1921, 40.7194, 44.3139, 37.7520, 39.2365, ...
```

I wonder if this also works in your environment.
Do you use specific tensors as mu_students or teacher_pred?